# Problem with sending Get request from jenkins pipeline job from Jenkins slave

Tags: jenkins, httprequest

I am using HTTP-request in Jenkins pipeline job to send Get request from Jenkins slave, the response code is 200, response content is null, but if I send the request from Jenkins master, I can get response content correctly, how can I solve this problem? below is the command I used HTTP-request in Jenkins pipeline

```
httpRequest acceptType: 'APPLICATION_JSON',
   authentication:  env.MY_CREDENTIAL, 
   contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON',      
   url:  env.MyURI, 
   wrapAsMultipart: false
```

Comment: solved the issue with adding  responseHandle: 'STRING'

Comment: If you wish, you can answer your own question, since it appears you found a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing wrong with your request but as you commented, looks like the response is string?

You can add `consoleLogResponseBody` to see how the response looks like.

```
def response = httpRequest(
    authentication:  env.MY_CREDENTIAL, 
    consoleLogResponseBody: true,
    url:  env.MyURI, 
    wrapAsMultipart: false
)
```

And you should be able to parse it simply like this

```
def json = readJSON(text: response.content)
```